# Unable to run batch file from Wix

Tags: batch-file, wix, custom-action, wix3.5, velo

I am trying to run a batch from my wix code as below:-

```
<Binary Id="DeleteRegistryKey" SourceFile='C:\Docs\WixProject\WixProject\DeleteReg.bat'/>
        <CustomAction Id="RegHKCUCleaner" BinaryKey="DeleteRegistryKey" ExeCommand='' Execute="immediate" Return="ignore"/>
<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RegHKCUCleaner" Sequence="2"> </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

But, the batch file is not running at all.
In the ExeCommand attribute, I have also tried ExeCommand='cmd.exe /c C:\Docs\WixProject\WixProject\DeleteReg.bat' and ExeCommand='"C:\Docs\WixProject\WixProject\DeleteReg.bat"'
But, still the batch file is not running.

If I see the log, below error is found:-

```
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:669]: Running ExecuteSequence
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:669]: Doing action: RegHKCUCleaner
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:669]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 10:30:58: RegHKCUCleaner. 
Action start 10:30:58: RegHKCUCleaner.
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:682]: Note: 1: 1721 2: RegHKCUCleaner 3: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7ABC.tmp 4:  
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:682]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: Error 
MSI (s) (04:DC) [10:30:58:682]: Note: 1: 2228 2:  3: Error 4: SELECT `Message` FROM `Error` WHERE `Error` = 1721 
Info 1721.There is a problem with this Windows Installer package. A program required for this install to complete could not be run. Contact your support personnel or package vendor. Action: RegHKCUCleaner, location: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI7ABC.tmp, command:  
Action ended 10:30:58: RegHKCUCleaner. Return value 1.
```

Comment: For <InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="RegHKCUCleaner" Sequence="2"> </Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
I have also tried After="CostFinalize"
But still, the batch file isn't running.

Comment: Running batch files from MSI is an **anti-pattern**. Very clunky and not at all good for *error handling* and *reliability*. HKCU registry keys are considered "user data" and should generally be left behind - potentially with instructions on how to clean them out manually. This is for many reasons, most significantly because the user might have settings there they wish to preserve (licenses for example) and the fact that you can only clean out one HKCU hive anyway - leaving other users with all the settings in there still. A battle you can not win. Don't add error prone features for no gain?